# process id and killing process - ps commmand

Tags: process, kill, ps

Please see the output of below **ps** command:

```
abc@smaug:~/Desktop$ ps ax | grep firefox
 2213 ?        Sl     2:01 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 2644 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto firefox
```

Please explain both rows and what process id can be used to kill firefox process?

Process id **2644** keeps on changing everytime I run that command.

Comment: `kill -9 2213` will do the job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

when trying to find the PID of `firefox`, you launch a new process that filters all the unwanted processes. this filter process (`grep firefox`) also contains the search-term "firefox" and thus finds itself.

whenever you restart `ps ax | grep firefox` you launch a new `grep`-process, hence it's PID keeps changing.

So, the short answer is:

> use PID 2213 to kill firefox

If you want to get rid of the false positive, you can use another `grep` to filter it out:

```
 $ ps ax | grep firefox | grep -v grep
```

yet another option is to use `pgrep` (which will only give you the PID of the found processes)

```
 $ pgrep firefox
 2213
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already explain why you see two mentions of `firefox`. That's why the way to do what you are attempting is not to parse `ps` but to use the `pkill` and `pgrep` commands:

```
   pgrep,  pkill  -  look  up  or signal processes based on name and other
   attributes
```

For example, to find running instances of `firefox`:

```
$ pgrep -l firefox 
1020 firefox
```

To kill them:

```
$ pkill firefox
```

Answer (score 1):

The firefox process you have to kill is:

```
2213 ?        Sl     2:01 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

The 2644 process is the grep command you are running, which, as you mention correctly, change his ID every time you keep running it.

Answer (score 1):

one-liner:

```
ps aux | grep firefo[x] | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: Awk and grep is redundant; awk can do pattern matching: `awk '/firefox/ {print $2}'`...